# Why "Inbox" keeps "Sent" messages along with replied to messages in "Inbox"?

Tags: gmail

I´m using Gmail.

I answer a message in the "Inbox", I know my answer will go to the "Sent" folder WITH that message so I delete this message from "Inbox"...But I discovered that it deleted both that message AND my answer.  The answer NOT in "Sent" folder so it didn't get sent!!!

In Mozilla Thunderbird and Microsoft WLMail, the answer to a message goes into the "Sent" folder TOGETHER with the message replied to, so I can safely and efficiently delete the replied to message in the "Inbox" and keep that page nice and UNCROWDED.

I hope someone knows how to fix this please?  Thanks ever so much!

Comment: What web application are you using? Gmail, Inbox by Gmail, another?

Comment: Thank you Ruben, I use just my Gmail account.  Do you think there's a way to get both my answer AND the replied-to message into "Sent" so I can safely delete the replied-to message in "Inbox".  Thanks again.

Comment: Please checkout [ale's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/114039/88163)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Gmail, this is because Gmail by default groups messages into conversations. When you delete, you delete the entire conversation, which means all the messages in it.

You have two options if you don't want to delete entire conversations:

1. Turn off conversation view. This is available in the settings and makes Gmail act like traditional mail clients.
2. You *can* delete individual messages, but it's hidden in the action menu for the individual message. Open the menu and choose "delete this message".

Comment: Hi and thank you so much Ale.  Yes, I do use Gmail, and following your instructions I was able to turn off the conversation view.  I'll use it a while to see if I like it better.  Now that I know how to manage it, if I don't like it, I can try your No. 2 option.  THANKS AGAIN, A LOT!!!   :)